# Dictionary printing results backwards

Tags: dictionary, swift

In the video tutorial:

Quick unscripted tutorial introduction to apple Swift progrqmming language in 16 minutes
http://youtu.be/3tZig9AWMdc?t=9m10s

I did the same thing as him, but got the results backwards

```
var names = [
    "1" : "...",
    "2" : "...2"
]

for (k,v) in names {
    println("key is \(k) : value is: \(v)")
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
key is 2 : value is: ...2
key is 1 : value is: ...
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing nothing.

`Dictionary` is unordered collection.

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_185):

> Swift’s Dictionary type is an unordered collection. The order in which keys, values, and key-value pairs are retrieved when iterating over a dictionary is not specified.

Comment: so, even though it is unordered, why does it runs inconsistently on different devices?

Comment: Maybe the implementation was changed, I think. The video you referred is using very early beta version of Xcode 6.

Comment: Even if it does run inconsistently on different devices, it shouldn't matter at all. You should only access values with keys, so if you need your information to be ordered use an array.